# Vagrant create extra bridge for the second VM

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I am trying two create two virtual machine via one Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.box_version = "1707.01"

  config.vm.define "inf-vm-01" do |node|
    config.vm.hostname = "inf-vm-01"
    config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: "192.168.1.121"
  end

  config.vm.define "inf-vm-02" do |node|
    config.vm.hostname = "inf-vm-02"
    config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: "192.168.1.122"
  end
end
```

As you can see, I would like to build bridge between each guest machine and my host machine. The problem is that the second virtual virtual machine has an extra bridge. This is the output of **ip addr**:

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 52:54:00:ad:a0:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
           valid_lft 86303sec preferred_lft 86303sec
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fead:a096/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:1b:8e:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.1.121/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1b:8eeb/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:e1:d5:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.1.122/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee1:d5bc/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What is wrong with my vagrant file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong Vagrantfile, you're using `config.vm.network` within a block so its valid for the file. You should write like this (notice how I am using the node1 and node2 variable inside the block)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.box_version = "1707.01"

  config.vm.define "inf-vm-01" do |node1|
    node1.vm.hostname = "inf-vm-01"
    node1.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: "192.168.1.121"
  end

  config.vm.define "inf-vm-02" do |node2|
    node2.vm.hostname = "inf-vm-02"
    node2.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: "192.168.1.122"
  end
end
```

You can also read the [vagrant doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/), specifically the [Defining Multiple Machines](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/#defining-multiple-machines) chapter